# How to position div on a page?

Tags: html, css

Okay im really new to all of this and im starting the CSS part for my TAFE 
so here it is

I've been asked to add

- A list
- a table with 10 rows and 5 columns
- A background picture
- and three links.

But i can figure out how to position all of these things in different spots?

help? 
this is all I've got so far

it's sad

i know

```css
div {
  /* Purple box */
  height: 150px;
  width: 30%;
  border: 10px solid purple;
  background-color: purple;
}
/* link colour change and dots */

a {
  color: black;
}
ul.a {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
/* This Part is making the underline come on and off the links*/

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1> Welcome to Brakeys webpage </h1> 
</center>

<div id=a>
  <center>
    <p>Check out these awesome bands!:</p>
  </center>
  <center>
    <br><a href="http://violentsoho.com/">Violent Soho</a>
    </br>
  </center>
  <center>
    <br><a href="https://tiredlionband.bandcamp.com/">Tired Lion</a>
    <br>
  </center>
  <center>
    <br><a href="https://dunerats.bandcamp.com/">Dune Ratz</a>
    <br>
  </center>

</div>

<div id=b>
  <ol>
    Top 5 best bands
    <li>Nirvana</li>
    <li>Pearl Jam</li>
    <li>Pink Floyd</li>
    <li>Foo Fighters</li>
    <li>Bob Dylan</li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: take a look at CSS 'position' property

Comment: If you want to show them in one row then use float or display:inline-block;

Comment: There are in different spots, one below the other, it's just that there is no gap between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at the W3 CSS and Bootstrap tutorials:

http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Using bootstrap's grid system, you will be able to make the rows and columns you want, easier than you think. An example of a grid you may want to take note on:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">.col-sm-6</div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">.col-sm-3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that you shouldn't dive into bootstrap or other css premade collections until you have a solid foundation on how html & css work, which i don't think it's the case here

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this web site:

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

This is the best tutorial I've found about div positioning.